# Why my use statements are case sensitive in one environment and not in the ther one?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, php-8

Few days ago I faced a problem in my production environment. Let's say I've got a `FOOClass`.
When I tried to use it in another class, I made a typo in the use statement like so `use My\Namespace\FooClass;`

There was no problem in dev and test environment, but when I deploy my application in production, I've got an error because the application cannot find my class.

I'm using Symfony 5.4.25, PHP 8.1.23, Debian 11

I tried to find any configuration differences between environment (PHP configuration, Symfony configuration, server configuration, etc) but I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Is your development environment Windows ?

Comment: PHP class names are not case sensitive. However, when you auto-load classes you use the file system of the OS on which you run your code. Linux is case sensitive, Windows is not. So on Windows a file named `FOOClass.php` is the same as `FooClass.php`, whereas on Linux these are seen as two different files.

Comment: My development/test/production environment run on the same OS version, so it's Linux everywhere

Comment: Whenever you ask about an error, you should include the _exact_ error you're seeing. The details might not seem relevant to you, but may give clues to people helping you. In this case, it's important to know if the error was about not finding the _class_, or not finding the _file_; and the details of the error may also give clues about what file it was looking for, and what code was involved.

Comment: Are the two environments on the same filesystem with the same settings? For example; Ext4 and ZFS can be set to either case sensitive or insensitive, even per directory/dataset.

Comment: Mac systems had or has case insensitive systems, had the same issue several years ago